# Is it possible to access Web Workers from a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, web-worker

I have an app which contains several iFrames and Web Workers which communicate via postMessages. I am interested in creating a chrome extension which lists and display all of the messages in a comfortable and easy to inspect way.

Is there a way to access the workers from the window that created them, without a reference to the created instance? (i.e - can I get a list of workers on a given site from the chrome dev-tools console?) Would it be possible to retrieve this information from a chrome extension?

### Update

Since the Chrome Devtools Sources Panel does classify web-workers, I was hoping that this can be done with a [devtools extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools). I also searched through the frontend code of the devtools to understand how a worker is identified there and found [this](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/e8dd4b8f5e5e6100640e139d81da10995ebcc77b/front_end/sources/NavigatorView.js#L500), but am still unable to find how I can get a reference to the workers using the chrome extension api.

[image: Web-worker in Chrome Devtools Sources Panel]

Comment: There is no special chrome API for web workers but you can try chrome.debugger API and utilize [chrome remote debugging protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-getTargets) to inspect available contexts. And of course you can listen to `message` event on `window` in your content script.

Comment: Tried and unfortunately `chrome.debugger.getTargets` does not include Web Workers. It does include results with type `worker` but that only refers to `serviceWorker`s